# how does django query work?

Tags: django, django-queryset

my models are designed like so

```
class Warehouse:
    name = ...
    sublocation = FK(Sublocation)

class Sublocation:
    name = ...
    city = FK(City)

class City:
    name = ..
    state = Fk(State)
```

Now if i throw a query.

```
wh = Warehouse.objects.value_list(['name', 'sublocation__name', 
    'sublocation__city__name']).first()
```

it returns correct result but internally how many query is it throwing? is django fetching the data in one request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django makes only one query to the database for getting the data you described.
When you do:

```
wh = Warehouse.objects.values_list(
    'name', 'sublocation__name', 'sublocation__city__name').first()
```

It translates in to this query:

```
SELECT "myapp_warehouse"."name", "myapp_sublocation"."name", "myapp_city"."name"
FROM "myapp_warehouse" INNER JOIN "myapp_sublocation"
ON ("myapp_warehouse"."sublocation_id" = "myapp_sublocation"."id")
INNER JOIN "myapp_city" ON ("myapp_sublocation"."city_id" = "myapp_city"."id")'
```

It gets the result in a single query. You can count number of queries in your shell like this:

```
from django.db import connection as c, reset_queries as rq

In [42]: rq()

In [43]: len(c.queries)
Out[43]: 0

In [44]: wh = Warehouse.objects.values_list('name', 'sublocation__name', 'sublocation__city__name').first()

In [45]: len(c.queries)
Out[45]: 1
```

Comment: i am gonna spend hours now testing all my queries like this thanks

Comment: If your objects are rendered on an html page, you can use django-debug-toolbar instead. It'll do that for you :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to write a test for this using `assertNumQueries` ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries)).

```
from django.test import TestCase

from yourproject.models import Warehouse

class TestQueries(TestCase):

    def test_query_num(self):
        """
        Assert values_list query executes 1 database query
        """
        values = ['name', 'sublocation__name', 'sublocation__city__name']
        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            Warehouse.objects.value_list(values).first()
```

FYI I'm not sure how many queries are indeed sent to the database, 1 is my current best guess. Adjust the number of queries expected to get this to pass in your project and pin the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is extensive documentation on how and when querysets are evaluated in [Django docs: QuerySet API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/).

The pretty much standard way to have a good insight of how many and which queries are taken place during a page render is to use the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). This could tell you precisely how many times this recordset is evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use django-debug-toolbar to see real queries to db